# Make our PowerApps Canvas form look similar to SharePoint classic UI form (where the label & Input are on the same line and have space between them)

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms

Currently we are redesigning a SharePoint Online classic form to be Power Apps Canvas form. but the client want us to keep the same layout as for the classic SharePoint online form (as much as possible), where the classic SharePoint online form have the following main layout that we want to have inside Power apps form:-

1. The label + the Input are on the same line
2. there is a horizontal space between the label & the input field, as follow:-

[image: johnjohn123_0-1686668897683.png]

now i build a responsive Canvas power apps >> which contain a form, and it looks as follow:-

[image: johnjohn123_1-1686669042300.png]

so how i can make the Power apps form to look similar (as much as possible) to the classic SharePoint form, while keep the power apps form responsive. currently the power apps form and its control have these settings:-

1. As shown in the above picture >> the form is inside a horizontal layout container
2. Each Control has its width = Parent.width , as follow:-

[image]

3. Each label has its width = Parent.Width - 60 as follow:-

[image: johnjohn123_4-1686669308408.png]

4. Each Input has its Width = Parent.Width -60

[image]

where my Power Apps form is responsive to an acceptable level, so i want to keep the form responsive after applying the needed layout changes (mainly making the label and the input on the same line + add horizontal space between the label and the input) ,, can anyone advice how to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as selecting your form and change the `layout` from Vertical to Horizontal. You can then tweak the settings from there.

Comment: yes you are correct,, worked for me